# What mechanism can I use to allow my Firebase Auth users to SSO into Amazon Connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase-authentication, amazon-cognito, saml-2.0, amazon-connect

**Goal:** Allow Firebase Auth users to access Amazon Connect without having to enter another username and password

**What I've tried:**

Amazon Connect's Identity Management can be done via 3 ways:

1. Store Users with Amazon Connect
2. Link to an Existing Directory
3. SAML 2.0-based authentication

1) Doesn't support SSO

2) I tried to create a Directory in AWS Directory Service, but given the options (*AWS Managed Microsoft AD, Simple AD, AD Connector*), none of them seem to be compatible with Firebase. I'm not sure if there is a way to sync Firebase Auth users into one of the above listed ADs.

3) SAML seemed promising, however, it appears that Firebase can **use** a SAML Provider, but cannot **act** as a SAML provider.

Is there any solution that will allow me to have Firebase Auth users SSO into an Amazon Connect instance?

If there is no direct solution, is there even an indirect solution where, for example, Cognito is my primary auth, which provides Connect access, and then I use Cognito as the SAML provider for my Firebase Auth